# Locating a radar in a plane

Tags: calculus, geometry

> Given two located targets at $(x, y)=(- 2.0)$ and $(x, y)=(2,0)$. A radar, located in an unknown location of the $XY$ plane, and sends a pulse and in return receives pulses from the two targets. Between the two pulses received, there is a lag time of $2/c$ seconds, where $c$ is the speed of light. What is the locus of possible positions of the radar?

The travel time round-trip of a pulse between the radar and target is $2d/c$, where $d$ is the distance between the radar and the target.

My attempt: Let us denote the first target $A$ et and the second $B$
I compute the between the radar and the target $d=\sqrt{(x_r+2)^2+y_r^2}$ where $\text{Radar}(x_r,y_r)$, I have also the vector $\overrightarrow{AB}=(4,0)$ and the equation of the plane in the form $ax+by+cz+d=0$, here we have $ax+by+d=0$. In fact my problem is I don't know where I am going.

Any hint (please) on what I should do is welcome.

Comment: Your extra sentence was irrelevant.

Comment: @AhaanRungta: While the last statement regarding a hint may seem superfluous to you (and to me as well, really) the author has specifically indicated that such was their intention.

Comment: One thing I should point out is that the question is worded badly in one spot: $c$ is defined as roughly $3\times 10^8$ meters per second. So $2/c$ seconds doesn't actually make sense. Presumably their intention was that the difference in distances is $2$ in whatever units they chose. As for the problem itself: What geometric figure is defined by the _difference_ in distances to two separate points?

Comment: Not in the sense I meant, I'm afraid. sds's answer below is what I was getting at.

Comment: The possible position is given by $(x,y)=(x, \pm \sqrt{3}\sqrt{(x^2-1)})$

Comment: @Yass: I just used the information that has been given in the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition implies that the difference between distances from the radar to the two targets is 
$$\frac{1}{2}\times\text{roundtrip time delay}\times\text{speed}=\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{2}{c}\times c=1$$
The [locus of such points is a hyperbola with foci = targets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Difference_of_distances_to_foci).

You can also see that analytically by writing the equation $d_A=1+d_B$ (where $d_x=\text{dist}(\text{radar},x)$) and squaring it twice
to get rid of roots.

Comment: 'The condition implies that the difference between distances from the radar to the two targets is 2' : How did you get that ?

Comment: It's a well-known property of hyperbolae. It's comparable to the definition of the ellipse as: "the set of points for which the sum of the distances to the foci are constant."

Comment: @Yass: I edited the answer to make "2" more clear.

Comment: Well, it's just speed$=$distance/time, silly question.

Comment: I have to learn about hyperbola. Thanks a lot. (+1, and accept)

Comment: $d_A$ is the distance between $A$ and the radar ?

Comment: @Yass: yes, please see edit

Comment: @sds Thanks, I think I got it.

Comment: Just noticed one small but crucial mistake (which I made as well): The lag-time of $2/c$ seconds is for the radar to send a pulse out and _receive it back_. So the lag accumulates over both steps, and the correct difference in distance is $1$ rather than $2$. @Yass

Comment: Ha, right! Thank you @Semiclassical.